# Can BitLocker NOT ask for password on every single boot?

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

How to set up BitLocker on Windows 10 Pro to not ask for password on every single boot? But only if some suspicious activity happens, f.i. connected new USB drive?

No TPM module.

Comment: You need a TPM module for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no - it cannot be done without Trusted security devices.  There are several reasons for this.  All of the below is working on the assumption you have no TPM or other trusted security device in place and are working in a "password only" environment.

**An encrypted drive is encrypted**.  It is locked when a machine is off, it needs unlocking.  Its like asking if a car can be started without a key unless the driver is left handed.  When the machine is turned on, BitLocker doesn't know what is on the drive or how to unlock it.. your password forms a "key" component in the unlock process.

**Design** - allowing methods of password bypass would pretty much invalidate the purpose of encryption.  It would allow a new attack vector and a potential way around drive encryption.  In your scenario - I could steal your laptop and all I would have to do to unlock the machine would be **literally nothing** (i would have to NOT insert a memory stick).

**Definition**.  Defining "suspicious behaviour" would be ambiguous and would vary case to case.  While this could *probably* be handled programatically - it would open more attack vectors, would open machines to abuse, misconfiguration and a whole host of other potential security holes.